# Can I map the Mac "Command" Key in Vim?

Tags: vimrc

I've seen others use `nmap <D-V> <C-V>` for instance to map Command-V to Control-V but it doesn't end up working on my end.

Important: I should mention that I type code both on a virtual machine that runs Linux and on my Mac's terminal and the mappings don't work on either.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: What are you using for a terminal program?  Are you using the MacVim GUI?  In MacVim Command-i went into insert mode, but after I said `:nnoremap <D-i> A`, Command-i started insert mode at the end of the line.